# How do I pass an argument to a remote function when the argument value is not known until after render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototype

My html.erb template has this:

```
function f(arg) { 
<%= remote_function
:url => { :controller => "the_controller", :action => "the_action" },
:update => 'the_div',
:method => :post
%> ;}
```

I'd like to do something like

```
:id => arg
```

or

```
:with => "'arg=...'"
```

... but I don't know what the value of arg is until after the page has rendered and the user does something.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

`function x(arg) {
    <%= remote_function :with => '{id: arg}' %>
  }`

Comment: Thanks for the nudge.  This did the trick:

      :with => "'id='+ arg"

Comment: it's better to use hash-kind parameters to make sure all escaping and stuff is handled correctly